# modify existing char* or create a tmp char*?

Tags: c, pointers, char, c-strings, function-declaration

Some languages, like Java, require you to create another string in order to solve certain kinds of problems. But when it comes to C, when should you create another string and when should you simply modify an existing one?

take the following code as an example:

```
    char *removeTags(char *s, int length)
{
    if (!s || length < 1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *tmp = calloc(length, sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '<')
        {
            for (int k = i; k < length; k++)
            {
                if (s[k] == '>')
                {
                    i = k;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (s[i] != '>' && s[i] != '<')
        {
            tmp[count] = s[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

it should be called as following:

`char *foo = (char *)calloc(length, sizeof(char));  foo = removeTags(foo, strlen(foo));`

would it be better if i just modified the `char *s` instead of creating the `char *tmp` to help me?

Comment: When you want to keep the original copy, make a copy of the original.

Comment: @SparKot otherwise, should i always modify the original one? thank you for your answer!

Comment: Note that, whichever you do, you need to copy the terminating `nul` character. In the case of allocating a new string, make sure the length is enough for that.

Comment: Yes, modifying in place is the other (efficient) choice. If the memory was dynamically allocated, don't lose the base-addresses of the buffers. You'll need them for `free()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function deals with strings then the second parameter is redundant and error-prone

```
char *removeTags(char *s, int length)
```

If you want to create a new string then the function must be declared like

```
char * removeTags( const char *s );
```

That is the function parameter shall have the qualifier `const`.

If you want to change a string in place then the function must be declared like

```
char * removeTags( char *s );
```

Pay attention to that you may not change string literals.

If you pass to the function also string literals then the function must be declared like

```
char * removeTags( const char *s );
```

You could define the both functions but in this case you need to use different function names.

Comment: Also, `length` is likely better declared as type `size_t`.

Comment: thanks a lot, the length is really not necessary, it doesn't even make since, since i can just do strlen(smth).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you modify a string in a C function, there's one really good reason to make a copy of the string and modify and return the copy while making your input string argument a `const char *`.

Your caller won't invoke undefined behavior by passing in a string literal.  That would likely crash your entire process with something like a `SIGSEGV`.

Like this:

```
char *removeTags(const char *s);
```

In general, you don't need to pass a length for string operations unless you need to limit the range of the string you're operating one.

Another, less important reason:  the caller may not be done with the string and may need it unmodified.

If you then discover through profiling that the extra copy step causes performance or memory problem, then you can create another function, and call it something like this:

```
void removeTagsInPlace(char *s);
```

Note the difference in return value that makes the fact the string is modified in-place impossible to miss.

Comment: very well explained, thank you for you help! i will change it to const right now, also, i have no idea why i passed the length as a parameter, i think i was dealing with an array before.